# Javascript Slideshow - change div's background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to the web development world and I am still figuring things out.

So, I am trying to change a div's background image using javascript, and make it like a slideshow. I've already tested some scripts slideshow tutorials but they haven't worked so far. Any ideas? (In need to do this without the use of any webkits or jquery).

**The HTML code** with the     **The CSS code**

```
<div id="container">
    <article>
        <section id="order"> 
            <center>
                <a href="order.html">
                    <acronym title="order now">
                        <img src="images/ordernow.png" id="orderBut">
                    </acronym>
                </a>    
            </center>
        </section>
    </article> 
</div>

#container
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:90%;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:50px;
    clear:both;
    line-height:0;
    background-image: url(images/pizzabite.jpeg); 
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: You have an invalid enclosed html tags for `</a>` and `</center>`..

Answer (score 0):

since you are starting on coding out a slide show, why don't you try this simple slider with the full code provided. You could learn from there like i did.

http://fancybox.net/

http://jquery-plugins.net/divas-slider-multipurpose-responsive-jquery-slider (More sophisticated)